# Why doesn't my results equal to an array where the num is inserted while the array is sorted?

Tags: javascript

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {  
  // Find my place in this sorted array.   
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);  <br>      

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {  
    if (arr[i] >= num) {  
      arr = arr.splice(i, 1, num);  
    }  
  }  
  return arr;  
}  

getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50);
```

Comment: Kudos on posting (some of) the relevant code, but you also need to ask your question. Tell us what result you expect, tell us what the code is currently doing, what it *should* be doing, how it fails, where it goes wrong... Please: take a read of the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: <br> ?!?! And you know that arr.splice returns the spliced out elements, therefore being a one element array after the first iteration

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues that are preventing you from getting the result you want. First:

```
arr = arr.slice(i, 1, num); 
// [1,2,3,4].slice(3, 1) will be empty array
// [1,2,3,4].slice(1, 3) will be an array of [2,3]
```

argument 1 is the start index, argument 2 is the end index. You have them flipped so you will always return an empty array. Also, there is no 3rd argument to `Array#slice`. You don't throw an error because JavaScript is evil and will silently ignore it.

Secondly, you're only grabbing the first half of your array when you slice. You want to get the second half as well. As a side note, if you don't pass a second argument into `Array#slice`, it defaults to the end of the array. So if you're looking for something like this:

```
let currArray = [1,3,45,23,12,13]
let newNum = 100
let i = 5 //if you wanted to insert newNum at index 5
let newArray = currArray.slice(0, i).concat(newNum).concat(currArray.slice(i))
//[ 1, 3, 45, 23, 12, 100, 13 ]
```

Also, you should declare your variables. Undeclared variables will silently make them global variables, which is a big no-no.

`Array#splice` is the wrong (or at least illogical) method to use. Splice changes the original array itself. The return value of `Array#splice` is what you took out of the array. You really shouldn't do this because it messes up the index numbers and you can't see that change in your lines of code.

Comment: splice was the method, not slice. What if I use logical operator

Comment: @SunlightScreen Splice is the wrong method to use. Technically you can, but it's highly illogical. I can explain it. Give me a sec.